# Clicking a list item should display table related to that list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user selects the list item, the table associated with that list item should be displayed. I am having a brain block, I think I'm close to solving it or at least the idea on how to. Find the length of each, if the length equals one another, then create the show/click functionality. The answer should be one that can be used for hundreds of list items with different tables.

HTML

```
<div>
            <ul>
                <li id='one'><a href="#">number</a></li>
                <li id='two'><a href="#">othernumber</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>title</th><th>title</th><th>title</th><th>title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>blah</td>
                        <td>blah</td>
                        <td>blah</td>
                        <td>blah</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                <tbody id="table2" style="display:none">
                    <tr>
                        <td>blahTwo</td>
                        <td>blahTwo</td>
                        <td>blahTwo</td>
                        <td>blahTwo</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

JS

```
function count(){
    var list = jQuery('ul li')

    var table = jQuery('table tbody')

    if(table.length == list.length){
        jQuery(list).click(function(){
            //show the table length that is equal to the list length 

        })
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8np48uh7/)

Comment: What are the for loops in your JS supposed to do? The first one's `return` statement will immediately exit the surrounding function. You don't need the loops, you can say `if (list.length === table.length)`. *"When the user selects the list item"* - Not what you're asking, but how would a user who doesn't (who perhaps physically can't) use a mouse use your page? You should use anchors in the li elements so that they can be "clicked" from keyboard or mouse.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have fixed the question

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm your code confuse me, so i wrote my own. Is it work like u need? http://jsbin.com/motoseyupa/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to associate the list items to the tbody elements just based on their position in the list, you can make use of the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in conjunction with [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```js
var list = jQuery('ul li a')
var table = jQuery('table tbody').hide()
    
list.click(function(e) {
  table.hide().eq(list.index(this)).show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id='one'><a href="#">number</a></li>
    <li id='two'><a href="#">othernumber</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tbody id="table2" style="display:none">
      <tr>
        <td>blahTwo</td>
        <td>blahTwo</td>
        <td>blahTwo</td>
        <td>blahTwo</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```